How to Enable Defer Option for Azure Redis Enterprise Cluster (Terraform)?
I'm currently working on managing an Azure Redis Enterprise Cluster using Terraform. I need to enable the option to defer Redis DB version updates, which I know can be done manually through the Azure portal in the Advanced Settings. However, I can't seem to find any mention of this option in the Terraform documentation for Azure Redis.


resource "azurerm_redis_enterprise_cluster" "redis" {
  name                = var.redis_name
  location            = var.loc
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  sku_name            = var.settings.sku_name
  minimum_tls_version = var.settings.minimum_tls_version
  zones               = var.settings.zones
  tags                = local.tags

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [tags]
  }
}



Has anyone managed to configure this setting through Terraform? If so, could you provide an example or point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Looking to enable defer option through terraform

Hi @meher ashish,  Have you tried any code so far for the above requirement? If yes, please add the code to your question.

@VenkatV
**
'resource "azurerm_redis_enterprise_cluster" "redis" {
name                = var.redis_name
location            = var.loc
resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
sku_name            = var.settings.sku_name
minimum_tls_version = var.settings.minimum_tls_version
zones               = var.settings.zones
tags                = local.tags
lifecycle {
ignore_changes = [
tags
]
}
}'
**
I didn't find any option to add defer option

The Defer automatic major Redis version updates option is still in preview, which might be the reason Terraform hasn’t updated the parameter in their documentation. Alternatively, you can use the az redisenterprise update command within a Terraform null_resource block, as described in this Stack link.

Since I don't have an EA License to test this in my environment, you can enable the option through the portal and then export the resource using the Terraform export command. This will generate the code with the same configurations.

I hope this helps you to resolve your problem.

Yes, this workaround helps

The Defer automatic major Redis version updates option is still in preview.which might be the reason Terraform hasn’t updated the parameter in their documentation.

Alternatively, you can use any method below to update Defer automatic major Redis version updates option using terraform
Method: 1
You can use the az redisenterprise update command within a Terraform null_resource block to execute Azure CLI commands in Terraform, as described in this Stack link.
Redis Enterprise cache updated commands
Azure PowerShell
Update Redis Enterprise cache using PowerShell
Azure CLI
az redisenterprise update
Terraform code to use an Azure CLI command in a null_resource block
resource "null_resource" "powershell" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT
    Update-AzRedisEnterpriseCache -Name  "MyCache" -ResourceGroupName  "MyGroup" -MinimumTlsVersion  "1.2" -Tag @{"tag1" = "value1"}
    EOT
  }
}

Method 2:
Enable the same option from the portal and then export the configuration using the Terraform export command. This will generate the Terraform code with the configurations you manually set in the portal.
aztfexport   resource  --non-interactive --hcl-only -   <resourceName>

